# spring batch aggregate records from db as one single record

Tags: spring-batch

Is there any sample where we can implement aggregate item reader which reads data from db and aggregate them as one record based on some col value?

I saw similar sample where it reads data from file and aggregate them but not for db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for is what the Driving Query pattern of batch processing attempts to accomplish.  In essence, you use an `ItemReader` to return the main object (that has the id that you want to aggregate by).  From there, you use an `ItemProcessor` to enrich the item by querying for the rest of the data by that id.

You can read more about the Driving Query pattern and other batch processing patterns in the Spring Batch documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html

Comment: Awesome!!!! Great advantage of choosing spring stack for development as you guys are always there to suggest best options and make simple things simple and complex things possible.

Comment: This solution introduces N+1 problem

Comment: I would like to try the driving query pattern but I am not able to see an example for this with DB. Can one of you share sample code. I am very new to SpringBatch and I cannot wrap my head around this.